# Programme not Terminating in Multi-threaded environment -Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-threads, thread-synchronization

Trying to make a simple multi-threaded programme where it prints Factorial series where each number is printed by different Thread and at the end I am giving a report of which number printed by which thread.I have got the desired output but somehow my program is not terminating.

**Constraint: I am not allowed to use Concurrent Package**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Report {

  private long factorial;
  private String threadName;
  private int activeThreads;

  public Report(long factorial, String threadName, int activeThreads) {
      this.factorial = factorial;
      this.threadName = threadName;
      this.activeThreads = activeThreads;
  }

  public long getFactorial() {
      return factorial;
  }

  public String getThreadName() {
      return threadName;
  }

  public int getActiveThreads() {
      return activeThreads;
  }

  public void setActiveThreads(int activeThreads) {
      this.activeThreads = activeThreads;
  }

}

public class Factorial implements Runnable {

  public static ArrayList<Report> report = new ArrayList<Report>();
  private static int count;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("N: ");
      int n = in.nextInt();
    
      count = n;
    
      Factorial f = new Factorial();
      f.series(n);
    
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    
      // Series
      for(Report r : report) {
          if(r.getFactorial() == 1) {
              System.out.print(r.getFactorial());
          }
          else {
              System.out.print(r.getFactorial() + "*");
          }
      }
    
      System.out.println();
    
      // Report
      for(Report r : report) {
          System.out.println(r.getFactorial() + " printed by " + r.getThreadName() + " " + r.getActiveThreads());
      }
      ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
      System.out.println("In Main");
    
      in.close();
  }

  public void series(int n) throws InterruptedException {
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
          Thread t = new Thread(new Factorial());
          t.start();
      }
  }

  public synchronized void generate() {
      ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
      report.add(new Report(count--, Thread.currentThread().getName(), threadGroup.activeCount()));
      notifyAll();
      System.out.println("In generate" + threadGroup.activeCount());
  }
    


  @Override
  public void run() {
      generate();
      synchronized (this) {
          try {
              wait();
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
      System.out.println("In Run" + threadGroup.activeCount());
  }

  public static int getCount() {
      return count;
  }

  public static void setCount(int count) {
      Factorial.count = count;
  }

}
```

Although I know that we can kill the threads using **.stop()** but I think it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make synchronization effective (`synchronized`, `wait`, `notify`), you have to use the same instance.
In `series`, you create a new `Factorial` instance on each loop, making every thread to wait indefinitely.

```java
public void series(int n) throws InterruptedException {
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      // Thread t = new Thread(new Factorial()); // creates an new instance
      Thread t = new Thread(this);
      t.start();
  }
}
```

In the `run` method, you first call `notifyAll()` (through `generate`), and then `wait`.
The last created thread will `wait` after all the others are done.
One way or another, this last thread has to be notified.
It could be right after the `sleep` call, with:

```java
synchronized(f) {
    f.notify();
}
```

or maybe with a dedicated synchronized method.